# Eigenvalues of $-y''+x^2y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, spectral-theory

I need to find the eigenvalues of $-y''+x^2y$, that is, the values of $\lambda $ such that the equation

$$-y''+(x^2-\lambda )y=0$$
has solutions differents of $0$ in the interval $[0, \pi] $ with $y (0)=y (\pi)=0$. Can you help me, please?.

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful but such equation are called [Weber's equation](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Weber_equation).

Comment: What exactly does "find" mean? Numerically? And if symbolically, what makes you expect that such a solution exists?